# Openshift port forward using java camel route

Tags: java, redis, apache-camel, openshift

I'm new to `openshift` and `java`, and i'm trying to connect to a `REDIS` service hosted on openshift, so that i can push data onto it using a `camel route`.

I tried using from(exec:) in camel to run a shell file, but that didn't work as expected.

I tried to look in `Openshift-Rest-Client jar` but didn't find a way to connect to my pod with port forwarding from the code directly.

Does java have something which i can run to get back the port after the oc command

> oc port-forward %pod% %LOCAL_PORT%:%_REDIS_PORT%

And it can sustain the process so that the port stays connected during the run of my application.

Comment: Where is the java process running? Locally?

Comment: Yes. It is running locally. Its a spring boot app which i use to enable some camel routes. I'd like to feed this port forward into a route somehow but can't find a way